# How to read data from a text file

Tags: c, file, file-io, input

How do I read input from my text file? The input file is several lines long, and each line is of the format `city city distance` where there are two cities and the distance between them.

I have tried several things to read the input, but unfortunately those did not work. I need
to parse the individual values on each line. (Each line consists of 2 city names and the distance between them.) Any help would be appreciated.

```
data = fopen(argv[1],"r");
while(!EOF){

while(1){
    c=fgetc(data);
    inname=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
    if(c==' ')
        mode++;
    else    if(c=='\n'){mode=0;
        break;}
    else {
        switch(mode%3){
            case 0;
                for(i=0;fgetc(data)!=' ';i++){  
                    if(inname[count]!=NULL) {count++;inname=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));}
                    inname[count][i]=fgetc(data);}
                break;
            case 1; 
                if(inname[count]!=NULL){ count++;inname=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));}
                for(i=0;fgetc(data)!=' ';i++){  
                    inname[count][i]=fgetc(data);}
                break;                                      
            /*case 2;for(i=0;fgetc(data)!='\n';i++){    
                    dist[say]=atoi(str);}}}*/
                }}}count++;}
                `
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look into [fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/) for reading formatted input like this.

To read a line containing two strings and an int, you would have something like:

```
fscanf(data, "%s %s %d", &city1, &city2, &distance);
```

To read multiple lines until EOF, your code should be of the following form:

```
while(fscanf(data, "%s %s %d", &city1, &city2, &distance)!=EOF) {
  /* rest of your logic here */
}
```

Comment: U mean that if i write somethink like that `while(!EOF){ while(1){fscanf(data,"%s %s %d", &city1[i], &city2[i], distance[i]);} i++;} of course if all of them is double pointers

Comment: @MAK: `fscanf` returns the number of *items* read, not bytes.  Also, it would be a good idea to specify the max field width for the `%s` conversion specifiers.

Comment: i cant upgrade the answer because i do not have enough reputation