# get input from the file in C

Tags: c, file, input

i am new in programming and in stackoverflow that is why i sometime maybe can have simple questions when i code something and want to get input fromthe file`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int len1=0;
   FILE* p;
   char a;
   char b[10];
   p = fopen(argv[1],"r");
   while (1)
   {
      a = fgetc(p);

      if(a == ' ') break;
      else
      {
         len1++; 
         b[len1-1] = a;
      }
   }
   printf("%c\n", b0);
   return 0;
}
```

it gives segmentation fault and what is the reason?

Comment: Welcome - I have formatted the code to make it easier to read.

Comment: Same question [posted 20 minutes earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919409/getting-the-input-from-the-text-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

You have a buffer overrun. If you change your `while` loop to stop after reading ten characters, even if *space* has not been reached, you should do fine.

Additionally, you are passing a character at `b[len1]` into `printf`, and have it *interpreted* as a pointer. This will segfault no matter what.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int len1=0;
   FILE* p;
   char a;
   char b[10+1]; // <<== need one more byte for the terminator
   if (argc != 2)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Need to supply a filename\n");
      return (-1);
   }
   p = fopen(argv[1],"r");
   if (p == NULL)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file %s\n", argv[1]);
      return(-2);
   }
   while (len1 < 10) // <<== avoid buffer overruns
   {
      a = fgetc(p);

      if(a == ' ') break;
      else
      {
         len1++; 
         b[len1-1] = a;
      }
   }
   b[len1] = '\0'; // <<== Don't forget to zero-terminate
   printf("%s\n", b); // <<== Pass the buffer, not the last character from it
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: it also gives segmentation fault in gcc compiler

Comment: @MiribraStacker There's probably something wrong with the file from which you are reading. I ran this at ideone using standard input [link](http://ideone.com/EjMIh), and it runs fine, both with and without a space in the input. Add a check after `fopen` to see if `p` is not NULL.

Comment: In that way it works, but I need to execute my program like      ./a.out input.txt

Comment: @MiribraStacker Did you add the check for `NULL` after the call to `fopen`? What does it return?

Comment: @Miribra Shacker - Added some error checking to the code (dasblinkenligh - hope you do not mind)

Answer (score 0):

`char b[10]` only has 10 elements. `len1` is incremented every iteration of an infinite loop. This quickly becomes > 10. Eventually somewhere past 10 you write into some memory you don't have access too. Hence the seg fault.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `while (1)`, you should **test the loop index** against the size of your table b (so 10)

What do you want to do exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems

1. What happens when you read the file and the first 10 characters are not a space? The array b will be esxhausted.
2. `printf` is trying to print a string. `b[len1]` is a character.

Answer (score 0):

There are two logical bugs in your program ::
1.`while(1)` you are having an non-terminating loop, it will result into stackoverflow.
2. `char b[10]` here, b is a char array of size 10 i.e. `b[0] to b[9]`, but as in your program `len1++` is executing for every iteration, which will access memory beyond `b[9]`.

To overcome these issues use `while(len1<10)`.